What's the magic number 0xa282ead8 seen in many CRC implementations?
I see the magic number 0xa282ead8 in many CRC implementations, like
https://github.com/kubo/snzip/blob/master/crc32.h
I don't understand CRC calculation very well. What's the effect of this number and what will happen if I change it?

It's something Snappy defines, not inherently related to CRC

See the explanation and specification here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/snappy/+/bfbc527a5740c894ba6f626ad62b17d786629851/framing_format.txt .
Copied from that:

Checksums are not stored directly, but masked, as checksumming data
and then its own checksum can be problematic.

This has nothing to do with CRCs, other than I presume their property that the CRC of any message followed by its CRC (with the proper byte ordering) is always the same constant. For some reason unbenownst to me, that is "problematic".
The only thing that happens if you don't follow the specification is that you're not following the specification. The receiver may be expecting that you do.

Could you explain a little more about "checksumming data and then its own checksum can be problematic"? If I only care about the CRC of payload data, is this mask not necessary?

As I said, I do not know what exactly is "problematic". You do not need the masking if you are in control of both the sending and receiving ends, in which case you can simply compute the CRC on one end, and check it on the other. You would only need to do the masking if the receiver is expecting that you follow the linked specification.
